# Not receiving notifications from pushbots

Tags: android, push-notification

Everythings seems to work fine on my dashboard of pushbots.It is showing the devices that are registered and when i push notification it shows a message that notification is dilevered but on phone i am not getting it.This is my manifest file.I have followed http://pushbots.com/developer/docs/android this guide.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<permission android:name="com.illudia.karwan_e_quran.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.illudia.karwan_e_quran.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive dataf message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.illudia.karwan_e_quran.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.illudia.karwan_e_quran.MESSAGE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

This is my MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);
    Pushbots.sharedInstance().setPushEnabled(true);}
```

This is my logcat
03-02 18:27:44.531: I/PB2(12107): PushBots Library v2.0.9AS
03-02 18:27:44.541: V/PB2(12107): number of receivers for com.illudia.kaarwanequraan: 2
03-02 18:27:44.541: V/PB2(12107): Found 1 receivers for action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
03-02 18:27:44.541: V/PB2(12107): Found 1 receivers for action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
03-02 18:27:44.561: V/PB2(12107): Is registered on server: true

Comment: am also having the same problem.  did u got  any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem this is your full manifest. Make sure your manifest contains that part which sets default push receiver class.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.example.sampleapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.DefaultPushHandler" />
<service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
        <service android:name="org.openudid.OpenUDID_service" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: i have added that part but i dont know why its not showing that part here.Is it necessary to add google play store library to this project??